# jquery - add an event handler to an object population

Tags: javascript, jquery

im sorry but I don't know how to call this code. Hence, the title.

```
    $("#e12").select2({
     width: "resolve",
     tags: ["Cardiologist", "Anesthesiologist", "Neurologist", "Gynecologist", "Andrologist"]
  });
```

That is the code that is populating my `input` element. However, I want to add an event handler for that. How can I add this?

```
$('#e12').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

P.S. Please tell me what my first code is called.

Comment: the first code is initializing the select2 plugin, so I guess it should be call __"initialization of the plugin"__

Comment: What kind of event handler do you want? click, hover, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

Your first code is using **select2 plugin** and is `initializing` your input with data, which will be used by that `input` after on.

And use **keydown**

```
$('#e12').on("keydown",function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

They're a [little different](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html). In this case, keypress isn't inserting anything into your field.

Comment: It is still not working. I can still press enter in the input field.